# how to get posted form data in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have posted data using $.ajax method from view.I am not getting posted data in controller
I have tried in different ways to get data but not succeeded.
Here is my code posted

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "/Groupage/UpdateAddresses",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "JSON/Application",
            data: JSON.stringify(sr)
        });


[HttpPost]
public void UpdateAddresses(IEnumerable<GroupageAddress> addresses,FormCollection coll)
 {
       //saving data in db
        var list = Request.QueryString.Cast<GroupageAddress>();
        var list1 = Request.QueryString.Cast<IEnumerable<GroupageAddress>>();
      //getting null for addresses parameter
     //Used request

 }
```

here is groupage address class properties

```
   public class GroupageAddress
    {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Transport Job Id")]
    public int GroupageJobId { get; set; }
    public int TransportJobId { get; set; }
    //Company name is not required
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "County")]
    public string County { get; set; }
    [Required]

    [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Global Transport Job Address Type Id")]
    public int GlobalTransportJobAddressTypeId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Time From")]

    public DateTime? TimeFrom { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Time To")]

    public DateTime? TimeTo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Actual Time")]

    public DateTime? ActualTime { get; set; }

    public int GroupageAddressSequenceId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
    public virtual GroupageJob GroupageJob { get; set; }
   }
```

here is posted form data
[image]

Comment: What is the ContentType of the request?  What is the class definition of GroupageAddress?

Comment: content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 ,I have posted serialized data of list of GroupageAddress class I am edit list of GroupageAddress object.

Comment: And the code from the view itself is where?

Comment: It's look like your data is JSON, but you're telling MVC it's Form data.  Either set the Content Type to `JSON/Application; charset=UTF-8` or correctly format the data to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: After changing contentType to json/application browser sending data in the form of request payload but still in controller I am getting null value

Comment: Return a JsonResult instead of void

Comment: I want to save data using ajax request not required anything to return

Comment: The correct content-type for json data is `application/json`

Comment: i am getting data to controller after changing application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that based on content type mvc will respond to data.
I have used just $.post("/Groupage/UpdateAddresses",JSON.stringify(sr)) but it sent content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
When I used the with like below
content type is changed to "Application\JSON"

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "/Groupage/UpdateAddresses",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "Application/JSON",
        data: JSON.stringify(sr)
    });
```

Got the data deserialized in the form of C# object as parameter in method.